# How to build Indexes in my sharepoint site with out effect of other sites in Central administration

Tags: sharepoint-2007

How to build Indexes in my SharePoint site without effect of other sites in Central Administration

Answer (score 0):

You could either create a new scope for your Shared Service Provider and have your site target that scope only, or create a full new SSP for that site only.

P.S. this belongs to server fault.